# how to concate two datafield in a datagridcolumn?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

how to concate two datafield in a datagridcolumn?

Comment: Please use proper grammar and define your question better, otherwise this question is likely going to get flagged. By me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that your question is to show two data fields from the data provider as data for a `dataGridColumn`. 
You can use `labelFunction` for the `dataGridColumn`.

Here is a sample.

```
    [Bindable]private var myDataProvider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                            {fname: 'fname 1', lname: 'lname 1'},
                            {fname: 'fname 2', lname: 'lname 2'},
                            {fname: 'fname 3', lname: 'lname 3'}
                        ]);

    private function myLabelFunction(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String {
        return  item.fname + ' ' + item.lname;
    }

    <mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{myDataProvider}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn labelFunction="{myLabelFunction}" headerText="Full Name" />
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

use labelFunction for the dataGridColumn.[

```
private function concat(item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String
        {
            return (item.id+""+item.catCode);
```

//use this in datagrid

if use dataprovider as arraycollection you can declare as

```
[Bindable]private var cat:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
```

i hope this is enough when you get data from users by entering in textfields... using form....:-)